# What is the most straight forward, easy to verify algorithm to construct a valid password from a character stream?

Tags: algorithms

Let's say we are given an infinite character stream like the following:

```
nqDoo8NkPsDn0gVf(pAI)dwa^Vq7OfAgt@KDUkjN5ZXY1yK6w7ygW6S&@L0EsUEq9...
```

What is the most straight forward way to construct a valid password from the stream? A valid password must pass a number of conditions, for example:

1. At least 8 character long
2. Consist of both lower & upper characters
3. Consist of at least 2 special characters

(Or other common password validations)

In addition, the result should depends on the input stream. That is, a same input should result in a same password and a significantly different input should yield a different password (most of the time). This is because using same / very similar passwords for all users is no good for security concerns.

The algorithm should be as straight forward as possible so a human can easily verify the result, given the same character stream and set of conditions.

My first attempt:

1. Pick the first condition from the set. E.g. `Consist of both lower & upper characters`
2. Build a string that fulfills this condition. Skip any characters not taken. E.g. Take `nD` from the stream `nqDoo...`
3. Repeat for the other conditions and concat each of the result string. E.g. `nD` -> `nD()` -> ...
4. Pad with immediately upcoming characters to fulfill length requirements. E.g. `nD()` -> `nD()dwa^`

Problem 1: 
The result depends on the ordering of the conditions which cannot be logically determined. I feel like this is unnecessarily implementation dependent and can be confusing without access to the source code.

Problem 2: 
I am not sure how to handle special conditions such as "Do not contains dictionary words". Should I check after step 4 and start over with the unused characters if these special conditions fail? Yet another confusing step for verification.

What is a better algorithm?

Comment: Do you need the returned string to be a substring of the stream? 
If so, you can return the shortest contiguous substring of the stream that starts at the beginning of the stream and is valid (notice that the property of being valid is monotone w.r.t. extension, so you can efficiently check this).  

If it does not need to be a substring of the stream, then a constant string like "Abcdef@^" satisfies conditions 1 to 3, is straighforward, and is immediate to verify. 

In other words, I think that you are missing some condition on the distribution of the passwords you want to return :)

Comment: @Steven You're right. I've edited the question for clarification. Besides, I'm not sure how likely the contiguous substring approach would run into infinity; wouldn't it be practically unverifiable if it requires checking like 1,000,000 substrings? The verifier can search the string but he / she would not know whether it is the first valid substring or not

Comment: The conditions are still too weak.  Suppose I have a dictionary of 100 constant strings that meet conditions 1-3, and I ignore the input stream and randomly select from the dictionary, or I hash the input stream and use it to select from the dictionary.  That meets all of your stated conditions but is a very poor method for choosing passwords.

Comment: @D.W.♦ randomly selecting words does not fulfill the condition that `a same input should result in a same password`. How can such a dictionary be generated anyway? If there's such an algorithm that would be the answer to the question.

Comment: So consider my variant with hashing.  That satisfies that requirement but still is a poor method for choosing passwords.  Such a dictionary could have strings like "Abcdef@^", "Gfhijkl!+", etc.; it is trivial to generate.

Comment: @D.W.♦ Wouldn't such approach return the same password most of the time? Say 10,000 different inputs are given to this algorithm, 99% of those would return duplicated password from the 100 words. This does not satisfy the requirement `different input should yield a different password (most of the time)`.

Comment: I interpreted that part of the question to mean "if I pick two different inputs, then with high probability the resulting passwords are different".  I think you need to formalize your requirements more carefully.  Separately: I'm lacking understanding of the motivation or context behind the specific requirements, so I'm losing motivation for engineering solutions that meet those particular requirements.  There are standard solutions for picking good passwords and I'm not clear why those aren't adequate in practice.